# How do I dynamically unregister a Connected App which was dynamically registered?

Tags: connected-apps, dynamic

How do I dynamically unregister a Connected App which was dynamically registered?

If I perform dynamically registration on package install, how do I dynamically unregister when the package is being uninstall?

Is there any mechanism provided for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have opened a Salesforce support case to get the following information.

There is no mechanism currently which provides this and Salesforce Support specialist suggested to open an idea for that.
I have opened such an idea.
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000KsMp7UAF/dynamically-unregister-a-connected-app-which-was-dynamically-registered

The possible workaround might be to use Metadata API to delete the connected app, however, you need then full admin access to the org where the connected app is created.

```
private static String dele(String name) {
    return ''
        + '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
        + '<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'
        + '<env:Header>'
        + '<urn:SessionHeader xmlns:urn="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">'
        + '<urn:sessionId>' + userInfo.getSessionId() + '</urn:sessionId>'
        + '</urn:SessionHeader>'
        + '</env:Header>'
        + '<env:Body>'
        + '<deleteMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">'
        + '<type>ConnectedApp</type>'
        + '<fullName>' + name + '</fullName>'
        + '</deleteMetadata>'
        + '</env:Body>'
        + '</env:Envelope>'
    ;
}
private static void val(HttpResponse r) {
    System.debug('success? ' + r.getBody().contains('<success>true</success>'));
    if (!r.getBody().contains('<success>true</success>')) {
        throw new UnexpectedException(r.getBody().substringBetween('<statusCode>', '</statusCode>') + ': ' + r.getBody().substringBetween('<message>', '</message>'));                  
    }
}
  
public static HttpResponse del(String name) {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/Soap/m/50.0');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    req.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
    req.setBody(dele(name));
    HttpResponse r = new Http().send(req);
    System.debug('add getBody: ' + r.getBody());
    System.debug('add getStatus: ' + r.getStatus());
    System.debug('add getStatusCode: ' + r.getStatusCode());
    val(r);
    return r; 
}
del('ConnectedAppName');
```

Comment: Why there isn't a way to unregister: the dynamic client registration (DCR) is based on OpenID Connect [DCR spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html). Unfortunately the management operations such as update or delete on a registered client never made it to the spec. [RFC 7592](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7592) has these operations but it's in the experimental (read: far from accepted consensus) state.